# Popup search results for selected text in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search, firefox-extensions, selection, blogging

Often, I want to add a relevant hyperlink for a blog post, but I find the tab switching really clumsy.

Is there a Firefox addon/userscript that can:

- search Google/Bing for selected text,
- display the results in a popup/layover/AwesomeBar/etc, and
- let me copy the URL of the first search result? (for example, right-click context menu)

I know each of those pieces are out there, but I'd really like to accomplish all three at once.

Solutions that no longer work:

- the [Ubiquity Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mozilla-labs-ubiquity)
- the [LookItUp2](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/9620) userscript

Answer (score 0):

I found grabbed a patched version of Ubiquity from [here](https://bitbucket.org/satyr/ubiquity/). Works perfectly.